# How to make td (table cell) height to be the same as an < a> (link element) height?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have created a simple example https://jsfiddle.net/9usfctbp/ that contains the issue.

There is a code from fiddle:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#">
        Link
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```
a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
}
```

Expected result: td has height 16px the same as a link.

Actual result: td has height 18px that is 2px more than a link height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try removing the padding from the td elements :

```css
/* if you only want to keep the same height */
td {
   padding-top: 0;
   padding-bottom: 0;
}

/* or remove the padding from all edges */

td {
   padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: M. EH. Thank you. I was inattentive and didn't see td has a 1px padding

Answer (score 0):

set `margin`,`padding`, `border`, `td` element to 0 and set its `line-height` property to same value of `font-size` of the a element

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  line-height: 16px;
}

a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#">
        Link
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```